# Plesk 11.5 PHP-FPM error: server reached max_children setting (5), consider raising it

Tags: nginx, max, children, plesk, php

Does anyone know how I might solve this particular error in a multi-domain VHOST Plesk environment?

```
server reached max_children setting (5), consider raising it
```

There are a number of domains listed in the /etc/php-fpm.d/ folder, which contain the following settings:

```
pm.max_children = 5
pm.process_idle_timeout = 10s
; Following pm.* options are used only when 'pm = dynamic'
pm.start_servers = 3
pm.min_spare_servers = 3
pm.max_spare_servers = 5
```

Is there a way to change this globally? Each conf file comes with a warning not to alter the file directly since the changes will be overwritten when the files are re-generated.

ANy ideas?

Comment: well for me the folder is `/etc/php5/fpm/pool.d` i don't know what's `/etc/php-fpm.d/`

Comment: Are you sure that all of our virtual hosts are need to increase this setting? It's possible to find out which vhost generating this error message?

Comment: This is for a PLESK server. the location of the files is /etc/php-fpm.d/ .. I can increase the settings manually, but I am hoping for a solution that will not be replaced by plesk.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In all each php-fpm config files there is a notes from Parallels:

> To override pool configuration options, specify them in
>   [php-fpm-pool-settings] section of
>   /var/www/vhosts/system/domain.tld/conf/php.ini file.

As I see there is no way to tune this setting by plesk utilities or from GUI.

There is template:

```
/usr/local/psa/admin/conf/templates/default/domain/service/fpm.php
```

but this template is for nginx, not for php-fpm configs.